# How do I check that login and password entered is valid

Tags: java, android, sql

I am trying to create a login funcitonality in android studio in which I verify  entered password and login exist in database and go together(based on information in the login database) This should happen when the user clicks "button check login" 
If the info is accurate it should take the user to a welcome screen.

I am struggling with how to check the information according to the database. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

**Please look at following :**

DataBaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.login;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version) 
{
           super(context, name, factory, version);
}
// Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
// to create a new one.
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) 
{
        _db.execSQL(LoginDataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);

}
// Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
// of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
{
        // Log the version upgrade.
        Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");


        // Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new version. Multiple
        // previous versions can be handled by comparing _oldVersion and _newVersion
        // values.
        // The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");
        // Create a new one.
        onCreate(_db);
   }  

}
```

LoginDataBaseAdapter.java

```
public class LoginDataBaseAdapter 
{
        static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";

        static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
        // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
        // SQL Statement to create a new database.
        static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
                                     "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text); ";

        // Variable to hold the database instance
        public  SQLiteDatabase db;
        // Context of the application using the database.
        private final Context context;
        // Database open/upgrade helper
        private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
        public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
        {
                context = _context;
                dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

         // Method to openthe Database  
        public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
        {
                db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                return this;
        }

        // Method to close the Database  
        public void close() 
        {
                db.close();
        }

         // method returns an Instance of the Database 
        public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
        {
                return db;
        }

          // method to insert a record in Table
        public void insertEntry(String userName,String password)
        {


                   ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
                    // Assign values for each column.
                    newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
                    newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);



                    // Insert the row into your table
                    db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "User Info Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

       // method to delete a Record of UserName
        public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
        {

               String where="USERNAME=?";
               int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;
               Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return numberOFEntriesDeleted;

        }

   // method to get the password  of userName
    public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
    {


            Cursor cursor=db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
                return "NOT EXIST";
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
            return password;


    }

 // Method to Update an Existing Record 
    public void  updateEntry(String userName,String password)
    {
            //  create object of ContentValues
            ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
            // Assign values for each Column.
            updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
            updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

            String where="USERNAME = ?";
            db.update("LOGIN",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});

    }


 }
```

SignUpActivity.java

```
public class SignUPActivity extends Activity
{

        EditText   editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword;
        Button btnCreateAccount;

        LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.signup);

                // get Instance  of Database Adapter
                loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
                loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

                // Get Refferences of Views
                editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
                editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
                editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);

                btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);


                btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                        String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

                        // check if any of the fields are vaccant
                        if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals(""))
                        {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                        }
                        // check if both password matches
                        if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Does Not Matches", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                // Save the Data in Database
                                loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, password);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }


                    }
                });
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();

            loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow pseduo code:

```
 final String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
            if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
                emailEditText.setError("Invalid Email");
            }

            final String pass = passEditText.getText().toString();
            if (!isValidPassword(pass)) {
                passEditText.setError("Invalid Password");
            }
// validating email id
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}

// validating password with retype password
private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
    if (pass != null && pass.length() > 6) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I am actually trying to check the password and login with those stored in the database