# Retrieving DB information using RecyclerView and Fragments

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

1. How can I Retrieve data in CategoryListFragment with 'getCategories()?'
   I've GetAllValues() function in MyDBHelper, but not sure how to use it @fragments class, because I can't initialize MyDBHelper object correctly, when I try it.

**MyDBHelper.class**

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME="CategoryDatabase";

public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Category (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT);");

}

@Override

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Category");

    onCreate(db);

}

public void addCategory(String name)

{

    ContentValues values=new ContentValues(1);

    values.put("name", name);

    getWritableDatabase().insert("Category", "name", values);

}

public Cursor getCategories()

{

    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select * from Category", null);

    return cursor;

}

public ArrayList<String> GetAllValues()
{
    String aTable = "Category"; // Table's name
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor =  getCategories();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
    {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return list;
}
}
```

Comment: please add your logcat output or errors.

Comment: Please look at my answer and initialise DBadapterClass in oncreateView() method in fragment calss.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570129/how-do-i-check-that-login-and-password-entered-is-valid/40570657#40570657

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fragment class initialize MyDatabaseHelper  object like this

```
MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
```

and in the getCategories method fetch it like this

```
ArrayList<String> list = dbHelper.GetAllValues();
```

**EDIT:**

```
public ArrayList<String> GetAllValues()
{
String aTable = "Category"; // Table's name
ArrayList<Category> list = new ArrayList<>();
Cursor cursor =  getCategories();
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do
    {
       Category cat  = new Category(cursor.getString(0));
        list.add(cat);
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
{
    cursor.close();
}

return list;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
try to add fragment like this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.test_container, fragment, "CategoryFragment").commit();
```

Comment: It worked, but now getCategories () returns ArrayList with Strings, instead of Categories (object), so how should I manipulate my CategoryAdapter to still have it running? - First day learning fragments, and I don't feel like messing up my adapter, so it would be great if u could help me out.

Comment: i edited my answer. If it help you upto some extent can i get an upvote. Thankss

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me out with second question as well?

Comment: Can you give me full code for 2. question? Right now, it's missing 'fragment'parameter.

Comment: this will be your CategoryListFragment fragment = new CategoryListFragment();

Comment: My app crashes at start.. and in debugger it says - frame is not available.